# Doubts about object Casting

Tags: java

[image]

I am helping a friend from first year to prepare his exam on Java.
The teacher asked them to create a method that can cast a Musicians to a Poets.

No one knew how to do it. After thinking a good while, I came to the conclusion that it is impossible to do that(**ClassCastException**), because the fact that Musician and Poet Share an Interface is not enough to cast them to the other.

I think that would be possible only, if they were in the same inheritance chain.

Now I have three questions:

1. Am I right?
2. If I am right, what is what the professor wanted from them to do? I really doubt that he would ask for such a thing.
3. If I am wrong, could you write code that can cast a Musician into a Poet?

Comment: Is "cast" the actual word used in the phrasing of the request ?

Comment: Assuming cast is the exact word used it's either a trick question or a typo.

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu That is a good question. He just said that the method should be called `musicianToPoet(String fileName)`, didnt mention return type, and also said that the Musician values should be rode from a very simple .txt file

Comment: @awoodland The proff is such a nice guy, it has to be a typo, i don't he would make such trick questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are right
2. Trick question?
3. No, at least, not without a `ClassCastException`.

You could try:

```
 Musician musician = new Musician();
 Artist artist = musician;
 Poet poet = (Poet)artist;
```

But of course, that code won't actually work at runtime.

Comment: Yeah. Probably it was a trick question :)
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Given your inheritance structure, you cannot cast a `Musician` to a `Poet`.

The only thing you could do is create a facade object that is a `Poet` and forwards relevant method invocations to an associated `Musician`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can i ask you just something else(I think ther is no need to open new ticket, it is very simple). Do you think if there was no super class and Poet and Musician just implemented that interface, the problem still the same right?

Comment: @sfrj correct, you can only cast up the inheritance chain, not sideways or down.

Comment: Yes, it's still the same whether the two classes share a common superclass and/or interface.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw ideas around... can you use the java.lang.reflect.Proxy class?

Edited..

Actually you don't need the Proxy as I mentioned. Using ideas I borrow from dynamic sub-classing, you can achieve your goal of convert musician to poet. Basically what you do is 
you have to create a class that extends Poet, takes in a Musician in constructor. Then in the sub class you can override each of Poet's method to "map" Poet's method to Musician's method.

I have written all stuff in one class, which is not a good programming style, but it's just easier to do on SO ;-)

```
public class Caster {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Musician m = new Musician();

        Caster caster = new Caster();

        Poet p = caster.cast(m);

        System.out.println(p.getPoetryGenre());

    }

    public Poet cast(Musician m){
        Poet p = new PoetWannabe(m);

        return p;
    }

    private class PoetWannabe extends Poet{

        private Musician musicianInDisguise;

        public PoetWannabe(Musician m){
            this.musicianInDisguise = m;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPoetryGenre() {
            return musicianInDisguise.getMusicGenre();
        }

        @Override
        public void setPoetryGenre(String g) {
            musicianInDisguise.setMusicGenre(g);
        }

        /*override more methods as you wish*/
    }

}
```

Comment: Never heared about it. What is it?

Comment: I see what you did. Pretty interesting, but probably not a really good approach from the design point of view. Thank you very much for your help. 1+ for cool class name `PoetWannabe` :)

Comment: Actually, I think this design is ok, because it's kind of an example of adapter pattern. "PoetWannabe" is adapter that expose "Musician" as "Poet". That said, I agree with you that this can be a bad design depending on the context of the problem, so I am wondering what was your reason for thinking this as bad design?

Comment: Well i didn't say bad, i said not good approach. I was thinking just in the context of the problem as a hold. This 1st years students have not yet understanding of patters. The proff is teaching them some basic principles like polimorphism, inheritance... I think he wanted to make them do some type of casting, but probably made some mistake when designing the exercise. Thanks for sharing your point of view :)

Comment: Oh yes point taken! I'm sorry if I sounded defensive, I didn't mean to. I just want to get people's input so I can improve myself ;-) I actually agree with you that for a first year Java 101, it can be a mistake from the prof. Maybe the correct answer to your question then be "email the prof for clarification".

Comment: You didn't sound defensive it is good to think that way(I also think that way). To improve we always have to ask,propose, critic and be critized. ;-) I will tell my friend to email the prof or the assistant for clarifications. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can Musician and Poet each be an interface?  If so it's possible to have a class that implements both and could be cast from a Musician to a Poet and vice versa.

```
public interface Musician {
  void sing();
}

public interface Poet {
  void read();
}

public class Common implements Musician, Poet {
  public void sing() {
    //sing
  }

  public void read() {
    //read
  }
}


public Musician convert(Poet poet) {
  if(poet instancof Musician) {
    return (Musician) poet;
  else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a musician");
  }
}

public void test() {
  Common rapper = new Common();
  Musician singer = convert(rapper);
}
```

Comment: Well i am not sure. Musicians and Poets have attributes, and that is not allowed in interfaces. Could you update your post and make a little suggestion on how could i improve that example? I don't get what you are suggesting.

Comment: I see your update. Yes, i understand now. That could be simple solution. Maybe something like that is allowed, but the only problem is that the attributes that are unique for Musician and Poet, have to be together in Common class.

Thanks, that was helpful.

Comment: In the end I think it is a "trick question" to make sure you understand that Java does not have multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

```
static Poet musicianToPoet(String fileName) {
    Poet p = new Poet();
    p.readArtist(fileName);  // this method is defined in the interface
    return p;
}

static Poet musicianToPoet(Musician musician) {
    String filename = "/some/file/name.txt";
    musician.saveArtist(filename);
    return musicianToPoet(filename);
}
```

Comment: Cool this is a really good trick. Thanks! You dont cast at all but you manage to transform the Musician into a poet. Also important you respect the definition of the methods given in the interface. 1+

Answer (score 0):

```
public Musician getMusician(Poet p) {
    Artist a = p;
    return (Musician)a;
}
```

Yes, this will explode with a ClassCastException. But, at least from a language level, it SEEMS like it can be done. But the runtime will prevent it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, Musician and Poet are different classes that share the same base implementation. The only thing that you could reliably do is cast IArtist<->Artist<->Musician, or IArtist<->Artist<->Poet

Answer (score 0):

With the class diagram you have there.  NO, you cannot cast a Musician to a Poet.  Are you sure the prof isn't asking you/your friend to redesign the class tree?

Comment: I don't think so. But if yes. What UML structure would you suggest to allow that type of casting? How should the students organize the classes(Notice that Musicians and poets are different things).

Comment: You'd have to generalize the Musician class from the Poet Class(i.e move one of the arrows).  Make it so that all musicians are also poets.   (although you'll get plenty of argument about that).     However, when you're done, you won't need the type-cast.